# Asterisk service and error logging

Tags: asterisk

How can I log Asterisk service (service status, e.g. service is running or stopped) and Asterisk errors in a remote database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, with the `/etc/asterisk.logger.conf` you can have errors go to a syslog, which you can parse for errors and put into a DB. To check the status I recommend a bash script that looks for asterisk running and sends that status to mysql (if last column ordered by datetime) is different then the current status insert it into the db. You can use cron to check status every few minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash

APP=`ps -aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep 'asterisk'`

# 1 is false in BASH
APP_RUNNING=1
if [ $APP != "" ]; 
then
  APP_RUNNING=0
fi
```

Comment: After googling for a few days, I think your solution is the best solution. I've started to develop a php program to monitor asterisk service status that can be accessible over network.